# Why d3 does not work in NW.js

Tags: d3.js, nw.js

**[UPDATE]**: it turns out the npm version D3 not works, I change to CDN version, and everything works, but I still wonder what is wrong with require("d3")

---

All:

I am pretty new to NW.js, currently I am trying to use D3 in it, but even the basic d3.select can not work, any idea? The only thing work with select is `d3.select("body")`

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script>
var d3 = require("d3");
function barChart(){

    var width, height;

    function render(root){


        root.append("svg")
            .attr({
                width:width,
                height:height
            })
            .append("rect")
            .attr({
                width: 0.5*width,
                height: 0.5*height
            })
            .style({
                fill:"red"
            })



    }

    render.width = function(value){
        if(value != undefined){
            width = value;
            return render;
        }
        return width;
    }
    render.height = function(value){
        if(value != undefined){
            height = value;
            return render;
        }
        return height;
    }



    return render;
}


// this does not work
var root = d3.select("#app");
var chart = barChart();
chart.width(400).height(400)
chart(root);

</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I installed `d3` using `npm` and had to write this to get it work:

```
win.on('loaded', function() {
    d3_root = d3.select(document);
});
```

Now I can use `d3_root.select()` instead of `d3.select`.

As I understand it is because of `nwjs` context, you are working on "server" side in your script, so you have to choose document first. If you write code directly to html file `d3.select()` should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why?

Comment: Again. NWJS have 2 contexts: node context and browser context. Browser context is all <script> tags on html page and all scripts by default in html. Node context is - code imported and called by `require`. Code on page - browser code, code behind require - is node code. And you can call browser code in node and call node code in browser. NWJS allow to interact 2 context like you work in one conext and have one core, but in real, nwjs just switch context dinamically and have 2 js cores.

Answer (score 2):

You load d3 in nodejs context. Try to load it in browser context:

```
<script src="js/dependencies/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, so you mean I can not use the way like require("d3") to work with DOM?

Comment: DOM is part of browser context, not node context. In node context you don't have DOM and all other browser API (because it is node). But, you can work with DOM from node context by transferring DOM elements in node context. Anyway, if you want use browser lib - load it in browser context. If node lib - load it in node context. Some libraries can work in node and in browser well - moment.js for example.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I have not figured out is, how can I manage dependency if I just include them without thinking order?

Comment: Emm... Any way you like. You can manually set the order or use any script for this.